# Laravel Routes/jQuery $.post() returning 404 Not Found

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel-4

Javascript file including jQuery that sends the POST request.

```
$.post('sign_in', { email: email, password: password }, function(result) {
    $('#sign_in_result').html(result);
    console.log(result);
});
```

Laravel routes.php file that includes the POST route.

```
<?php

Route::get('/', 'HomeController@showWelcome');

Route::post('sign_in', function() {
    return 'Test';
});
```

Rather than returning test, nothing is returned.  In the console it's showing 404 Not Found.

```
POST http://localhost/project/public/sign_in 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the URL class to build the URL to your route, so:

$.post('sign_in', ....

becomes:

$.post('{{ URL::to('sign_in') }}', ....

Comment: Also, when debugging, you could try making sure that a 'get' request works, and test the URL in your browser and make sure it works, and then switch it over to being a POST when things look good.